# Is there any way to generate inline assembly programmatically?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

In my program I need to insert NOP as inline assembly into a loop, and the number of NOPs can be controlled by an argument. Something like this:

```
char nop[] = "nop\nnop";

for(offset = 0; offset < CACHE_SIZE; offset += BLOCK_SIZE) {

    asm volatile (nop
            :
            : "c" (buffer + offset)
            : "rax");

}
```

Is there any way to tell compiler to convert the above inline assembly into the following?

```
   asm volatile ("nop\n"
                 "nop"
            :
            : "c" (buffer + offset)
            : "rax");
```

Comment: You can't pass the assembly template string in as a char * variable.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Why do you need this?

Comment: @EricPostpischil The operands are irrelevant. Need to control the rate of cache priming by inserting NOPs inside for loop.

Comment: What do you mean by “rate of cache priming”? Are you trying to throttle the speed at which some code executes? There are other ways than inserting nops. And, if you did need to execute a variable number of nops, you can do a computed jump into a sequence of them. This smells of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You ought to fully explain the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, the inline asm template needs to be compile-time constant**, so the assembler can assemble it to machine code.

If you want a flexible template that you modify at run-time, that's called JIT compiling or code generation.  You normally generate machine-code directly, not assembler source text which you feed to an assembler.

---

For example, see this complete example which generates a function composed of a variable number of `dec eax` instructions and then executes it.  [Code golf: The repetitive byte counter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/the-repetitive-byte-counter/160236#160236)

BTW, `dec eax` runs at 1 per clock on all modern x86 CPUs, unlike NOP which runs at 4 per clock, or maybe 5 on Ryzen.  See http://agner.org/optimize/.

A better choice for a tiny delay might be a `pause` instruction, or a dependency chain of some variable number of `imul` instructions, or maybe `sqrtps`, ending with an `lfence` to block out-of-order execution (at least on Intel CPUs).  I haven't checked AMD's manuals to see if `lfence` is documented as being an execution barrier there, but Agner Fog reports it can run at 4 per clock on Ryzen.

---

But really, you probably don't need to JIT any code at all.  For a one-off experiment that only has to work on one or a few systems, hack up a delay loop with something like

```
for (int i=0 ; i<delay_count ; i++) {
    asm volatile("" : "r" (i));  // defeat optimization
}
```

This forces the compiler to have the loop counter in a register on every iteration, so it can't optimize the loop away, or turn it into a multiply.  You should get compiler-generated asm like `delayloop: dec eax; jnz delayloop`.  You might want to put `_mm_lfence()` after the loop.

Comment: @Johan : He said 4 or 5 **per** clock

Answer (score 4):

Well, there is this trick you can do:

```
#define NOPS(n) asm volatile (".fill %c0, 1, 0x90" :: "i"(n))
```

This macro inserts the desired number of `nop` instructions into the instruction stream.  Note that `n` must be a compile time constant.  You can use a switch statement to select different lengths:

```
switch (len) {
case 1: NOPS(1); break;
case 2: NOPS(2); break;
...
}
```

You can also do this for more code size economy:

```
if (len & 040) NOPS(040);
if (len & 020) NOPS(020);
if (len & 010) NOPS(010);
if (len & 004) NOPS(004);
if (len & 002) NOPS(002);
if (len & 001) NOPS(001);
```

Note that you should really consider using `pause` instructions instead of `nop` instructions for this sort of thing as `pause` is a semantic hint that you are just trying to pass time.  This changes the definition of the macro to:

```
#define NOPS(n) asm volatile (".fill %c0, 2, 0x90f3" :: "i"(n))
```